# How to determine the current interactive shell that I'm in (command-line)

Tags: bash, unix, shell, csh, tcsh

How can I determine the current shell I am working on?

Would the output of the `ps` command alone be sufficient?

How can this be done in different flavors of Unix?

Comment: Testing for particular capabilities (e.g. does it do `!` substitution?) is probably more portable than finding the name of the shell. Local custom might have you running something named `/bin/sh` which could actually be ash, dash, bash, etc.

Comment: @msw: Seems like a good comment except it leaves me wondering "how?".

Comment: It appears that there is no simple answer to this question.  If we can't _query_ the shell, maybe the better approach is to always _specify_ the shell.  I'm not sure that this is always possible, but maybe it is more easily accomplished than people generally assume.

Answer (score 969, accepted):

- There are three approaches to finding the **name** of the current shell's executable:

  Please note that all three approaches can be fooled if the executable of the shell is `/bin/sh`, but it's really a renamed `bash`, for example (which frequently happens).

  *Thus your second question of whether `ps` output will do is answered with "**not always**".*

  1. `echo $0` - will print the program name... which in the case of the shell is the actual shell.
  2. `ps -ef | grep $$ | grep -v grep` - this will look for the current process ID in the list of running processes. Since the current process is the shell, it will be included.

     This is not 100% reliable, as you might have *other* processes whose `ps` listing includes the same number as shell's process ID, especially if that ID is a small number (for example, if the shell's PID is "5", you may find processes called "java5" or "perl5" in the same `grep` output!). *This is the second problem with the "ps" approach, on top of not being able to rely on the shell name.*
  3. `echo $SHELL` - The path to the current shell is stored as the `SHELL` variable for any shell. The caveat for this one is that if you launch a shell explicitly as a subprocess (for example, it's not your login shell), you will get your login shell's value instead. If that's a possibility, use the `ps` or `$0` approach.

  ---

- If, however, the executable doesn't match your actual shell (e.g. `/bin/sh` is actually bash or ksh), you need heuristics. Here are some environmental variables specific to various shells:

- `$version` is set on tcsh
- `$BASH` is set on bash
- `$shell` (lowercase) is set to actual shell name in csh or tcsh
- `$ZSH_NAME` is set on zsh
- ksh has `$PS3` and `$PS4` set, whereas the normal Bourne shell (`sh`) only has `$PS1` and `$PS2` set. This generally seems like the hardest to distinguish - the *only* difference in the entire set of environment variables between `sh` and `ksh` we have installed on Solaris boxen is `$ERRNO`, `$FCEDIT`, `$LINENO`, `$PPID`, `$PS3`, `$PS4`, `$RANDOM`, `$SECONDS`, and `$TMOUT`.

UPDATE: Someone brought up "`ash`" (Almquist Shell) in comments. There seem to be 2001 variants of it including `dash`; so in the interest of not blowing up the answer unnecessarily, here's a very useful page listing a ton of various flavours of `ash` and their differences from each other and often from stanard Bourne `sh`: [https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/ash/](https://www.in-ulm.de/%7Emascheck/various/ash/)

Comment: ${.sh.version} is set on ksh93

Comment: `ps -p $$` as [Matthew Slattery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327013/how-to-determine-the-current-shell-im-working-on/3327108#3327108) points out. For `ksh`: `echo $KSH_VERSION` or `echo ${.sh.version}`.

Comment: @Dennish - my ksh right now doesn't have KSH_VERSION set. and `echo ${.sh.version}` returns "Bad Substitution". See my solution above

Comment: @fpmurphy whatever ksh we have installed on Solaris boxen at work, obviously predates ksh93 as it odesn't have that set. Matter of fact, the ONLY difference in entire set of envionmental variables between `sh` and `ksh` is `$ERRNO`, `$FCEDIT`, `$LINENO`, `$PPID`, `$PS3`, `$PS4`, `$RANDOM`, `$SECONDS`, `$TMOUT`.

Comment: @DVK  Currently Solaris has a highly customized version of ksh88. The POR is to move to ksh93 for the next release.  See http://hub.opensolaris.org/bin/view/Project+ksh93-integration/ for more information.

Comment: None of this works if trying to access SHELL type from a python script.

Comment: This is confusing:

`$ ps | grep sh`  
`25736 pts/1    00:00:00 sh`  
`25740 pts/1    00:00:00 bash`

... where `/bin/bash` is an executable, and `/bin/sh` points to `dash`

Comment: @Viks - it would if you write a shell script to do so

Comment: In zsh, `echo $0` prints the name of the script, not the name of the shell.

Comment: _“`ps  -ef | grep …` … This is not 100% reliable as …”_ 
 
Using a simple regular expression via `egrep` or `grep -e` can easily bring the reliability up to for-all-intents-and-purposes 100%: `ps  -ef | egrep "^\s*\d+\s+$$\s+"`.  The `^` makes sure we're starting from the beginning of the line, the `\d+` eats up the UID, the `$$` matches the PID, and the `\s*` and `\s+` account for & ensure whitespace between the other parts.

Comment: for the heuristics +1. Really helpful

Comment: @SlippD.Thompson didn't work in GNU/Linux. But this seem to work: `ps  -ef | awk '$2==pid' pid=$$`

Comment: `pgrep` is better for grepping thru processes

Comment: None of those 3 give you *this* shell when running an executable script (or, more likely, a file sourced therefrom).  The heuristic approach is then the only reasonable one (and arguably more useful: test the features you need, and use what works).

Comment: None of the above works in busybox. There, you can get busybox shell by something like: `/ # busybox ash
ash: applet not found
/ # busybox hush
/ #`

Comment: `echo $SHELL` is IMHO the most useful and logical approach, because it exactly tells which shell is running.

Comment: $SHELL isn't available in powershell, is there an alternative for that case?

Comment: `$SHELL` is the wrong approach as it is set by `login(1)` not the shell.  If you launch a different shell (e.g. via `sudo -l`) `$SHELL` will still be set to the original user's login shell.

Comment: `$SHELL` is completely useless for determining the current shell: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74376285/what-is-the-purpose-of-shell

Comment: This answer is great, but didn't help me when playing with Chimera Linux and trying to determine what their /bin/sh actually is.  Since they say their userland is from FreeBSD I guess that means it's Almquist shell (ash, though not busybox ash) - if anyone knows how to differentiate this shell, you could improve this answer.

Answer (score 136):

`ps -p $$`

should work anywhere that the solutions involving `ps -ef` and `grep` do (on any Unix variant which supports [POSIX options for `ps`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/ps.html)) and will not suffer from the false positives introduced by grepping for a sequence of digits which may appear elsewhere.

Comment: Some shells have their own builtin version of `ps` which may not understand `-p` so you may need to use `/bin/ps -p $$`.

Comment: All the shells I'm familiar with understand `$$` except for `fish` with which you would have to use `ps -p %self`.

Comment: Actually, you shouldn't rely on a hard paths such as `/bin/ps`. `ps` could easily (actually it is quite normal nowadays) be installed in `/usr/bin`. `$(which ps) -p $$` is a better way. Of course, this will not work in fish, and possibly some other shells. I think it is `(which ps) -p %self` in fish.

Comment: In some minimal systems like a debian-slim docker container, ps might not be there. In that case this approachs still works: `readlink /proc/$$/exe`

Comment: if your `sh` is emulated by `bash`, ps -p give you `/usr/bin/bash` even you run it as `sh`

Comment: `$$` is the [Process ID of the script itself](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#PROCCID). And `ps $$` already works in many cases.

Comment: @Xyz instead of `$(which ps) -p $$`, why not just use `command ps -p $$` or `env ps -p $$`?

Comment: Or for easier parsing: `ps -o comm -p $$`, which prints only the relevant column (although still two lines). It's [still POSIX](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/ps.html). Possibly modify for other ways to get the correct `ps`, according to taste. @9265740/tmillr 's `command ps` [should call the POSIX `ps`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/). Also note that POSIX does not specify the path to `ps`, or any other executable, and also doesn't require `/proc/`. Final note: `/proc/` doesn't exist on macOS, and isn't - I think - enabled by default on BSD.

Answer (score 59):

Use [`-p $$`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/ps.1#p%7E2) to get info on the current process ID (`$$`), and [`-o`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/ps.1#o%7E2) to control the output formatting.

```
ps -p $$ -o 'comm='
```

or

```
ps -p $$ -o 'args='
```

Comment: This is a nice short one. I was using myself `ps -o fname --no-headers $$`.

Comment: Thanks. I found this the best option to use in a script to guard bash specific commands `test \`ps -p $$ -ocomm=\` == "bash" && do_something_that_only_works_in_bash`. (The next line in my script has the equivalent for csh.)

Comment: I've found that if you do this from within a subshell then it can lead to spurious extra lines by matching the parent's PID as well as the actual shell process.  For this, I use `-q` instead of `-p`: `SHELL=$(ps -ocomm= -q $$)`

Answer (score 48):

If you just want to ensure the user is invoking a script with Bash:

```
if [ -z "$BASH" ]; then echo "Please run this script $0 with bash"; exit; fi
```

or [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327013/how-to-determine-the-current-interactive-shell-that-im-in-command-line#comment99517912_15731952)

```
if [ -z "$BASH" ]; then exec bash $0 ; exit; fi
```

Comment: It shouldn't be closer to top, because it doesn't answer the question at all. If the question would be "How to check if script is running under bash", I vote for it.

Comment: @DawidFerenczy - This question is the top result when you search for that phrase though. In the long run, I think it's much more important that answers answer what people are looking for rather than answer what the original question was about.

Comment: In addition, the variable $BASH _is_ defined under tcsh if the tcsh is invoked from bash

Comment: This is very useful, thank you. Just adapted it a bit, putting this as the second line after `#!/bin/bash`: `if [ ! -n "$BASH" ] ;then exec bash $0; fi`. With this line the script is run using bash even if started using ksh or sh. My use case doesn't need command line arguments, but they could be added after `$0` if necessary.

Comment: I run my script using `sh <script file>` and `$BASH` is set to `/bin/sh`.

Answer (score 25):

You can try:

```
ps | grep `echo $$` | awk '{ print $4 }'
```

Or:

```
echo $SHELL
```

Comment: What's the point of grep followed by awk, when `/pattern/ { action }` will do?

Comment: # in zshell
    alias shell='echo ${SHELL:t}'

Comment: `$SHELL` environment variable contains a shell, which is configured as default for a current user. It doesn't reflect a shell, which is currently running. Also it's better to use `ps -p $$` than grepping $$ because of false positives.

Comment: The $SHELL env. variable points to the 'parent' shell, as specified in the POSIX spec:

**SHELL** This variable shall represent a pathname of the user's preferred command language interpreter.

Therefore the value of $SHELL may not be the current shell.

Comment: all within `awk`, `ps | awk '$1=='$$' { n=split($4,a,"/"); print a[n] }'`

Comment: SHELL does not refer to either the current shell, nor the parent shell. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74376285/what-is-the-purpose-of-shell

Answer (score 24):

`$SHELL` need not always show the current shell. It only reflects the default shell to be invoked.

To test the above, say `bash` is the default shell, try `echo $SHELL`, and then in the same terminal, get into some other shell ([KornShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KornShell) (ksh) for example) and try `$SHELL`. You will see the result as bash in both cases.

To get the name of the current shell, Use `cat /proc/$$/cmdline`. And the path to the shell executable by `readlink /proc/$$/exe`.

Comment: ... Provided you have `/proc`.

Comment: provided that your shall support $$ - e.g. fish does not.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30379934/fish-shell-how-to-get-the-pid-of-the-process-started-in-the-background

Answer (score 21):

There are many ways to find out the shell and its corresponding version. Here are few which worked for me.

**Straightforward**

1. $> **echo $0** (Gives you the program name. In my case the output was *-bash*.)
2. $> **$SHELL** (This takes you into the shell and in the prompt you get the shell name and version. In my case *bash3.2$*.)
3. $> **echo $SHELL** (This will give you executable path. In my case */bin/bash*.)
4. $> **$SHELL --version** (This will give complete info about the shell software with license type)

**Hackish approach**

$> ******* (Type a set of random characters and in the output you will get the shell name. In my case *-bash: chapter2-a-sample-isomorphic-app: command not found*)

Comment: csh does not have a version option.

Comment: All the information has already been available above. This answer adds nothing new.

Answer (score 14):

I have a simple trick to find the current shell. Just type a random string (which is not a command). It will fail and return a "not found" error, but at start of the line it will say which shell it is:

```
ksh: aaaaa: not found [No such file or directory]
bash: aaaaa: command not found
```

Comment: No good in a script. `echo 'aaaa' > script; chmod +x script; ./script` gives `./script.sh: 1: aaaa: not found`

Answer (score 13):

[ps](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ps) is the most reliable method. The SHELL environment variable is not guaranteed to be set and even if it is, it can be easily spoofed.

Comment: +1 $SHELL is the default shell for programs that need to spawn one. It doesn't necessarily reflect the shell that's currently running.

Answer (score 9):

I have tried many different approaches and the best one for me is:

```
ps -p $$
```

It also works under [Cygwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin) and cannot produce false positives as PID grepping. With some cleaning, it outputs just an executable name (under Cygwin with path):

```bash
ps -p $$ | tail -1 | awk '{print $NF}'
```

You can create a function so you don't have to memorize it:

```
# Print currently active shell
shell () {
  ps -p $$ | tail -1 | awk '{print $NF}'
}
```

...and then just execute `shell`.

It was tested under Debian and Cygwin.

Comment: As of my setup (Cygwin | Windows 7) your answer is the best one,  and 
***ps -p $$ | tail -1 | gawk '{print $NF}'***  
works even from cmd without $bash. Please note gawk instead of awk, as awk works only from bash.

Comment: @WebComer Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by "_works even from cmd without $bash_". Even if you would have Windows ports of `ps`, `tail` and `gawk`, cmd doesn't define `$$` as it's PID so it definitely cannot work under the plain cmd.

Comment: Why not simply `ps -p$$ -o comm=`?  POSIX says that specifying all headers empty suppresses the header completely.  We're still failing (like all the `ps` answers) when we're sourced by a directly executed script (e.g. `#!/bin/sh`).

Comment: this doesn't work with busybox ps (which is used on alpine)

Answer (score 7):

The following will always give the actual shell used - it gets the name of the actual executable and not the shell name (i.e. `ksh93` instead of `ksh`, etc.). For `/bin/sh`, it will show the actual shell used, i.e. `dash`.

```
ls -l /proc/$$/exe | sed 's%.*/%%'
```

I know that there are many who say the `ls` output should never be processed, but what is the probability you'll have a shell you are using that is named with special characters or placed in a directory named with special characters? If this is still the case, there are plenty of other examples of doing it differently.

As pointed out by [Toby Speight](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4850040/toby-speight), this would be a more proper and cleaner way of achieving the same:

```
basename $(readlink /proc/$$/exe)
```

Comment: This just errors on all Unices that don't provide `/proc`. Not all the world's a Linux box.

Comment: And if you *are* on Linux, we'd prefer `basename $(readlink /proc/$$/exe)` to `ls`+`sed`+`echo`.

Comment: This will give the name of the actual *executable*, not the actual *shell*. When the actual shell is linked as a busybox applet, say `ash -> /bin/busybox`, this will give /bin/busybox.

Answer (score 7):

My variant on printing the parent process:

```
ps -p $$ | awk '$1 == PP {print $4}' PP=$$
```

Don't run unnecessary applications when AWK can do it for you.

Comment: Why run an unnecessary `awk`, when `ps -p "$$" -o 'comm='` can do it for you?

Answer (score 5):

Provided that your `/bin/sh` supports the POSIX standard and your system has the `lsof` command installed - a possible alternative to `lsof` could in this case be `pid2path` - you can also use (or adapt) the following script that prints full paths:

```
#!/bin/sh
# cat /usr/local/bin/cursh
set -eu
pid="$$"

set -- sh bash zsh ksh ash dash csh tcsh pdksh mksh fish psh rc scsh bournesh wish Wish login

unset echo env sed ps lsof awk getconf

# getconf _POSIX_VERSION  # reliable test for availability of POSIX system?
PATH="`PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin getconf PATH`"
[ $? -ne 0 ] && { echo "'getconf PATH' failed"; exit 1; }
export PATH

cmd="lsof"
env -i PATH="${PATH}" type "$cmd" 1>/dev/null 2>&1 || { echo "$cmd not found"; exit 1; }

awkstr="`echo "$@" | sed 's/\([^ ]\{1,\}\)/|\/\1/g; s/ /$/g' | sed 's/^|//; s/$/$/'`"

ppid="`env -i PATH="${PATH}" ps -p $pid -o ppid=`"
[ "${ppid}"X = ""X ] && { echo "no ppid found"; exit 1; }

lsofstr="`lsof -p $ppid`" || 
   { printf "%s\n" "lsof failed" "try: sudo lsof -p \`ps -p \$\$ -o ppid=\`"; exit 1; }

printf "%s\n" "${lsofstr}" | 
   LC_ALL=C awk -v var="${awkstr}" '$NF ~ var {print $NF}'
```

Comment: this works in fish! but for me, fails in bash, because of the `-i` (-> ignore environment) option to `env` in the line where you check for `lsof` being available. it fails with: `env -i PATH="${PATH}" type lsof` -> `env: ‘type’: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 5):

My solution:

```
ps -o command | grep -v -e "\<ps\>" -e grep -e tail | tail -1
```

This should be portable across different platforms and shells. It uses `ps` like other solutions, but it doesn't rely on `sed` or `awk` and filters out junk from piping and `ps` itself so that the shell should always be the last entry. This way we don't need to rely on non-portable PID variables or picking out the right lines and columns.

I've tested on Debian and macOS with Bash, [Z shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell) (`zsh`), and [fish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friendly_interactive_shell) (which doesn't work with most of these solutions without changing the expression specifically for fish, because it uses a different PID variable).

Comment: Not on my machine - I am running several shells and ssh

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to check that you are running (a particular version of) Bash, the best way to do so is to use the `$BASH_VERSINFO` array variable. As a (read-only) array variable it cannot be set in the environment,
so you can be sure it is coming (if at all) from the current shell.

However, since Bash has a different behavior when invoked as `sh`, you do also need to check the `$BASH` environment variable ends with `/bash`.

In a script I wrote that uses function names with `-` (not underscore), and depends on associative arrays (added in Bash 4), I have the following sanity check (with helpful user error message):

```
case `eval 'echo $BASH@${BASH_VERSINFO[0]}' 2>/dev/null` in
    */bash@[456789])
        # Claims bash version 4+, check for func-names and associative arrays
        if ! eval "declare -A _ARRAY && func-name() { :; }" 2>/dev/null; then
            echo >&2 "bash $BASH_VERSION is not supported (not really bash?)"
            exit 1
        fi
        ;;
    */bash@[123])
        echo >&2 "bash $BASH_VERSION is not supported (version 4+ required)"
        exit 1
        ;;
    *)
        echo >&2 "This script requires BASH (version 4+) - not regular sh"
        echo >&2 "Re-run as \"bash $CMD\" for proper operation"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
```

You could omit the somewhat paranoid functional check for features in the first case, and just assume that future Bash versions would be compatible.

Answer (score 3):

None of the answers worked with [`fish` shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friendly_interactive_shell#Variable_assignment_example) (it doesn't have the variables `$$` or `$0`).

This works for me (tested on `sh`, `bash`, `fish`, `ksh`, `csh`, `true`, `tcsh`, and `zsh`; openSUSE 13.2):

```
ps | tail -n 4 | sed -E '2,$d;s/.* (.*)/\1/'
```

This command outputs a string like `bash`. Here I'm only using `ps`, `tail`, and `sed` (without GNU extesions; try to add `--posix` to check it). They are all standard POSIX commands. I'm sure `tail` can be removed, but my `sed` fu is not strong enough to do this.

Comment: I get `sed: invalid option -- 'E'` on bash 3.2.51 and tcsh 6.15.00

Answer (score 3):

Please try this helpful command.

```
echo $SHELL
```

Comment: $SHELL might not be the same as the executing shell.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $$ # Gives the Parent Process ID 
ps -ef | grep $$ | awk '{print $8}' # Use the PID to see what the process is.
```

From *[How do you know what your current shell is?](http://www.unix.com/unix-dummies-questions-answers/10390-how-do-you-know-what-your-current-shell.html)*.

Comment: It's not the parent process - it's the current process.

Comment: Using `grep $$` is unreliable. `ps -ef | awk -v pid=$$ '$2==pid { print $8 }'` is better, but why not just use `ps -p $$`?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a very clean solution, but it does what you want.

```
# MUST BE SOURCED..
getshell() {
    local shell="`ps -p $$ | tail -1 | awk '{print $4}'`"

    shells_array=(
    # It is important that the shells are listed in descending order of their name length.
        pdksh
        bash dash mksh
        zsh ksh
        sh
    )

    local suited=false
    for i in ${shells_array[*]}; do
        if ! [ -z `printf $shell | grep $i` ] && ! $suited; then
            shell=$i
            suited=true
        fi
    done

    echo $shell
}
getshell
```

Now you can use `$(getshell) --version`.

This works, though, only on [KornShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KornShell)-like shells (ksh).

Comment: "This works, though, only on ksh-like shells." Are you saying I have to verify the shell *before* running this? Hmm...

Comment: @jpaugh, the lists must be supported by the shell sourcing this code, which is not the case for `dash`, `yash` etc. Normally, if you are using `bash`, `zsh`, `ksh`, whatever - you shouldn't care about such things.

Comment: So you're counting bash as "ksh-like"? Got it. That makes more sense

Comment: @jpaugh, well, that's what I meant because `ksh`'s set of features is mostly a subset of `bash`'s features (haven't checked this thoroughly though).

Answer (score 1):

Do the following to know whether your shell is using Dash/Bash.

`ls –la /bin/sh`:

- if the result is `/bin/sh -> /bin/bash` ==> Then your shell is using Bash.
- if the result is `/bin/sh ->/bin/dash` ==> Then your shell is using Dash.

If you want to change from Bash to Dash or vice-versa, use the below code:

`ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh` (change shell to Bash)

**Note**: If the above command results in a error saying, /bin/sh already exists, remove the /bin/sh and try again.

Answer (score 1):

I like [Nahuel Fouilleul's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327013/how-to-determine-the-current-interactive-shell-that-im-in-command-line/11097703#11097703) particularly, but I had to run the following variant of it on [Ubuntu 18.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_.28Bionic_Beaver.29) (Bionic Beaver) with the built-in Bash shell:

```
bash -c 'shellPID=$$; ps -ocomm= -q $shellPID'
```

Without the temporary variable `shellPID`, e.g. the following:

```
bash -c 'ps -ocomm= -q $$'
```

Would just output `ps` for me. Maybe you aren't all using non-interactive mode, and that makes a difference.

Comment: ps on macOS (and *BSD?) dies not understand -q

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OS X (and FreeBSD):

```
ps -p $$ -axco command | sed -n '$p'
```

Comment: Tried this while using `zsh`, and it gave me `-bash`.

Comment: On my system (now), tested with bash and dash, this return `mutt`... :-b

Comment: On MacOS terminal (zsh) it gave me `sed`

Answer (score 0):

Grepping PID from the output of "ps" is not needed, because you can read the respective command line for any PID from the /proc directory structure:

```
echo $(cat /proc/$$/cmdline)
```

However, that might not be any better than just simply:

```
echo $0
```

About running an actually different shell than the name indicates, one idea is to request the version from the shell using the name you got previously:

```
<some_shell> --version
```

`sh` seems to fail with exit code 2 while others give something useful (but I am not able to verify all since I don't have them):

```
$ sh --version
sh: 0: Illegal option --
echo $?
2
```

Answer (score 0):

Get it with the `$SHELL` environment variable. A simple [sed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) could remove the path:

```
echo $SHELL | sed -E 's/^.*\/([aA-zZ]+$)/\1/g'
```

Output:

```
bash
```

It was tested on [macOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS), [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29), and [CentOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS).

Comment: It specifies which shell to run for programs started by shell, but not necessarily equals shell that is running. I.e. GNU screen won't set itself as `$SHELL` even it is IS user's login "shell".

Answer (score 0):

One way is:

```
ps -p $$ -o exe=
```

which is IMO better than using `-o args` or `-o comm` as suggested in another answer (these may use, e.g., some symbolic link like when `/bin/sh` points to some specific shell as [Dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almquist_shell#Dash) or [Bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29)).

The above returns the path of the executable, but beware that due to /usr-merge, one might need to check for multiple paths (e.g., `/bin/bash` **and** `/usr/bin/bash`).

Also note that the above is not fully [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX)-compatible (POSIX *ps* doesn't have `exe`).

Answer (score -1):

Kindly use the below command:

```
ps -p $$ | tail -1 | awk '{print $4}'
```

Comment: First one is nonsense, `echo $SHELL` does what you're trying to do and do it well. Second one also isn't good, because `$SHELL` environment variable contains default shell for a current user, not a currently running shell. If I have for example `bash` set as default shell, execute `zsh` and `echo $SHELL`, it'll print `bash`.

Comment: You are correct Dawid Ferenczy, We can  use ps command to determine current shell. [ # ps -p $$ | tail -1 | awk '{print $4}' ].

Comment: `echo $SHELL` may be rubbish:

`~ $ echo $SHELL
/bin/zsh
~ $ bash
bash-4.3$ echo $SHELL
/bin/zsh
bash-4.3$`

Answer (score -1):

This one works well on [Red Hat Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Linux) (RHEL), macOS, BSD and some [AIXes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_AIX):

```
ps -T $$ | awk 'NR==2{print $NF}'
```

alternatively, the following one should also work if [pstree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pstree) is available,

```
pstree | egrep $$ | awk 'NR==2{print $NF}'
```

Comment: Why the negative vote?

Answer (score -1):

You can use `echo $SHELL|sed "s/\/bin\///g"`

Comment: No, the `SHELL` environment variable just tells other commands which shell to invoke for you.

Answer (score -2):

And I came up with this:

```
sed 's/.*SHELL=//; s/[[:upper:]].*//' /proc/$$/environ
```

Comment: This will only work on *Linux*!  Not MacOS, nor BSD!!