# Git says remote ref does not exist when I delete remote branch

Tags: git

I ran `git branch -a`

```
* master
  remotes/origin/test
  remotes/origin/master
```

I want to delete my remote branch

I've tried

```
git push origin --delete remotes/origin/test
```

I got

> error: unable to delete 'remotes/origin/test': remote ref does not
>   exist

How is it not exist ?

I did a `git branch -a`, and I saw it listed.

Did I miss anything ?

Comment: `git branch -a` will list the branches in your local and not from your remote. Right?

Comment: I think all of them. I am not sure.

Comment: It will show the remote branches within your local. It will not list all the remote branches.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I delete a Git branch both locally and remotely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/how-do-i-delete-a-git-branch-both-locally-and-remotely)

Comment: @peterh Looks to me like it's really asking "why can't I delete a remote branch" (probably when the branch has been deleted off the remote but the remote ref is still present locally) and therefore, not a duplicate but could do with a clearer title

Comment: I made an edit to the title, hope this is closer to the question's intent

Comment: `git fetch --prune`

Answer (score 604, accepted):

The command `git branch -a` shows remote branches that exist *in your local repository*. This may sound a bit confusing but to understand it, you have to understand that there is a difference between a remote branch, and a branch that exists in a remote repository. Remote branches are *local* branches that map to branches of the remote repository. So the set of remote branches represent the state of the remote repository.

The usual way to update the list of remote branches is to use `git fetch`. This automatically gets an updated list of branches from the remote and sets up remote branches in the local repository, also fetching any commit objects you may be missing.

However, by default, `git fetch` does not remove remote branches that no longer have a counterpart branch on the remote. In order to do that, you explicitly need to *prune* the list of remote branches:

```
git fetch --prune
```

This will automatically get rid of remote branches that no longer exist on the remote. Afterwards, `git branch -r` will show you an updated list of branches that really exist on the remote: And those you can delete using `git push`.

That being said, in order to use `git push --delete`, you need to specify the name of the branch on the remote repository; not the name of your remote branch. So to delete the branch `test` (represented by your remote branch `origin/test`), you would use `git push origin --delete test`.

Comment: Also `git branch -r | grep "origin"` will help with big projects that use fork

Comment: So there are 2 reasons for getting this message from git: either the branch was already deleted on the server, or you wrongly prefixed the branch name with `remotes/origin/`. Or both.

Comment: I wonder why Git doesn't auto-complete the branch name upon keypress of tab when I type `git push origin -d ` followed by the first letter of the branch name.

Comment: @2540625 Because auto completion isn’t something that Git the command line program can do. There are integrations that allow you to do this though, for example explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12399002/216074). This completely depends on your shell though.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. I have employed such a solution, but apparently this is failing edge case of some sort.

Comment: A great reminder of how to best access to confusing topics in git! All of your suggestions worked and I learned something, [@poke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/216074/poke).

Comment: I am getting this error even though I can see that the branches exist on GitHub. As soon as I deleted them using GitHub and fetched, their references were correctly removed.

Comment: @poke May I ask If I want to push the "local remote branch" to remote instead of delete it?

Comment: @SCKU Just skip the `--delete` then to actually push your local branch to the remote.

Comment: NB: If your branch is in some other remote (not `origin`), the command becomes `git fetch --prune <remote name>`

Comment: This doesn't seem to be true. git branch -a has a lot of stuff in it, but I called the prune several times, (and again to be true), but it didn't affect the contents of git branch -a.

Comment: This one does the trick with the prune attribute.

Answer (score 160):

The meaning of `remotes/origin/test` is that you have a branch called `test` in the remote server `origin`. So the command would be

```
git push origin --delete test
```

Answer (score 34):

There's a shortcut to delete the branch in the origin:

`git push origin :<branch_name>`

Which is the same as doing `git push origin --delete <branch_name>`

Answer (score 15):

1. get the list of remote branches

```sh
git fetch # synchronize with the server
git branch --remote # list remote branches
```

2. you should get a list of the remote branches:

```sh
origin/HEAD -> origin/master
origin/develop
origin/master
origin/deleteme
```

3. now, we can delete the branch:

```sh
git push origin --delete deleteme
```

Comment: Nope, this gives the same error: `remote ref does not exist`

Answer (score 15):

I followed the solution by [poke](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35941658/11122122) with a minor adjustment in the end. My steps follow

 - `git fetch --prune`; 

 - `git branch -a` printing the following

     `master`

     `branch`

     `remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master`

     `remotes/origin/master`

     `remotes/origin/branch` (remote branch to remove)

 - `git push origin --delete branch`. 

 Here, the branch to remove is not named as `remotes/origin/branch` but simply `branch`. And the branch is removed.

Comment: +1 for the comment re: the branch name, I was trying to delete `origin/branch` when it should just be `branch`.

Comment: Yeah, mine was also not `remotes/origin/branch` even though `branch -a` cleary said the path was exactly that. It ONLY worked when I used just the branch name alone, as you said. So thx for posting as it  would have taken awhile before I tried that.

Comment: git fetch --prune flag solved it for me. Apparently only git fetch doesn't give an updated remote branch list.

Comment: Didn't work, I got the same error.

Answer (score 12):

Given that the remote branch is remotes/origin/test you can use two ways:

```
git push origin --delete test
```

and

```
git branch -D -r origin/test
```

Answer (score 10):

`git push origin --delete yourBranch`

Answer (score 7):

#### Quick Answer

You just need to prune the list (clean the list) since that branch does not exist anymore.
Run the following command

```
git fetch --prune
```

to verify run

```
git branch -r
```

You should see a new list with only existing remote repos

Comment: Doesn't help, git fetch --prune just removes the local ones.

Comment: Hey @kovarex, this solution is for someone whose remote repo is deleted but still persists locally. If you want to delete a remote repo run ```git push origin -d branch-name ```

Answer (score 4):

For me this worked $ ▶ git branch -D -r origin/mybranch

Details

$ ▶ git branch -a | grep mybranch
  remotes/origin/mybranch

$ ▶ git branch -r | grep mybranch
  origin/mybranch

$ ▶ git branch 
  develop
* feature/pre-deployment

$ ▶ git push origin --delete mybranch
error: unable to delete 'mybranch': remote ref does not exist
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@10.102.100.38:config/myrepo.git'

$ ▶ git branch -D -r origin/mybranch
Deleted remote branch origin/mybranch (was 62c7421).

$ ▶ git branch -a | grep mybranch

$ ▶ git branch -r | grep mybranch

Answer (score 3):

A handy one-liner to delete branches other than 'master' from origin:

```
git branch --remotes | grep -v 'origin/master' | sed "s/origin\///" | xargs -i{foo} git push origin --delete {foo}
```

Be sure you understand the implications of running this before doing so!

Comment: thanks for this code! this is the only git code I tested working on deleting all remote branches except master.

Answer (score 1):

`git branch -a` will list the branches in your local and not the branches in your remote.

And the error `error: unable to delete 'remotes/origin/test': remote ref does not exist` means you don't have a branch in that name in your remote but the branch exists in your local.

Comment: this is helpful. it solved my delete problem. i am wondering why 'git push --delete origin/test' did not work, while "git push --delete test" worked

Answer (score 1):

This should help:

1. `git fetch`
2. `git push origin --delete branchName`

Comment: This command doesn't work, the same error.

Answer (score 0):

For `windows`

```
git branch --remotes| %{ $_.Trim().Split("/")[1] }| ?{ $_ -ne 'master' } | | ?{ $_ -ne 'otherBranch' } | %{ git push origin --delete $_ }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried all of these answers. None of them worked for me. I think I had somehow criss-crossed some repos and branches. I fixed it in Visual Studio by going to Options -> Source Control -> Git Repository Settings -> Remotes. There I saw the thing I was trying to delete. I just selected it and clicked the remove button.

Answer (score -3):

```
git push origin --delete origin/test
```

should work as well

Comment: It should be git push origin --delete test