# git: pruning / removing old branches: "error: failed to push some refs"

Tags: git, github

Here is a list of some remote branches on my GitHub repo:

```
$ git branch -a  

warning: ignoring broken ref refs/remotes/remote/HEAD
* master
  origin
  restoration-effort2
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/remote/master
  remotes/remote/carousel
  remotes/bridgent/animate
  remotes/bridgent/enlarged-hover
  remotes/bridgent/master
  remotes/bridgent/Rayom-generator-app
  remotes/bridgent/scripts
  remotes/bridgent/bridgent-carousel
```

My intention / goal here is to delete all the ones which start with: ‘remotes’ (but not the two ‘masters’).

When I attempt to delete them, I get:

```
error: unable to delete 'remote/bridgent-carousel': remote ref does not exist
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:Nostrad/<project_name>.git'
```

So I Google ‘error: unable to delete remote ref does not exist’ which turns up a SO question/answer titled [Git says remote ref does not exist when I delete remote branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35941566/git-says-remote-ref-does-not-exist-when-i-delete-remote-branch)

Another guide I found (which includes similar advice but consolidated into a single helpful blog post) can be found [here](https://config9.com/apps/git/git-says-remote-ref-does-not-exist-when-i-delete-remote-branch/).

These two guides recommend using commands such as these:

```
$ git branch -D animate
$ git push origin --delete remotes/Rayom/animate
$ git fetch --prune
$ git push origin --delete <branch_name>
```

In my case these commands helped me eliminate many of my old obsolete branches that I no longer need however these commands won’t delete the remaining branches (listed above).  Inputting these commands (and including some variations) produces the following output:

```
$ git push origin --delete bridgent/Rayom-generator-app                        
error: unable to delete 'bridgent/Rayom-generator-app': remote ref does not exist
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:Nostrad/<project_name>.git'

$ git push origin --delete remote/bridgent-carousel 
error: unable to delete 'remote/bridgent-carousel': remote ref does not exist
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:Nostrad/<project_name>.git'

$ git push origin --delete Rayom-generator-app 
error: unable to delete 'Rayom-generator-app': remote ref does not exist
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:Nostrad/<project_name>.git'

$ git push origin :Rayom-generator-app 
error: unable to delete 'Rayom-generator-app': remote ref does not exist
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:Nostrad/<project_name>.git'

$ git branch --remote
<no output>

$ git remote prune origin --dry-run
<no output> 

$ git remote prune origin          
<no output>
```

So my primary question for all of you is: How do I delete  `remotes/bridgent/Rayom-generator-app` and all similar remote branches?

It’s also worth noting that when I replace `origin` with `remote`, I get similar output but what is different here is that remotes refer to the former git project’s name (which no longer exists):

```
$ git push remote --delete bridgent/Rayom-generator-app 
error: unable to delete 'bridgent/Rayom-generator-app': remote ref does not exist
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:Nostrad/<**former**_project_name>.git'

$ git push remote --delete remote/bridgent-carousel 
error: unable to delete 'remote/bridgent-carousel': remote ref does not exist
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:Nostrad/<**former**_project_name>.git'

$ git push remote :Rayom-generator-app 
error: unable to delete 'Rayom-generator-app': remote ref does not exist
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:Nostrad/<**former**_project_name>.git'
```

Comment: The error is because there is not any branch named `bridgent/Rayom-generator-app` in the `origin` remote (presumably your GitHub repo). Instead, there is a branch named `Rayom-generator-app` in a remote named `bridgent` which points at the URL for some other repo..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Run `git remote` and see if you have remotes named `remote` and `bridgent`.  (Use `git remote -v` to see the URLs associated with each remote.)

If you don't want to have a remote named `remote`, use `git remote remove remote` to remove it.  This will remove *all* of its remote-tracking names too.  Repeat for `bridgent` if / as desired.

If you *do* want to keep these remotes, but prune any remote-tracking names associated with those remotes, run:

```
git fetch remote --prune
```

and/or:

```
git fetch bridgent --prune
```

You can also run:

```
git fetch --all --prune
```

(or `git fetch -a -p` for short).  The `--all` means *contact all remotes*.  Or, you can use `git remote update --prune`; `git remote update` defaults to fetching from all remotes.  The default for `git fetch` is generally just to call up, and hence update, `origin`.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, the default for `git fetch` is to call up the remote based on the *upstream* of the current branch, but if that's not set, it uses `origin`.  Most Git repositories tend to have only one remote, named `origin`, so this works well.  Your Git repository has *three* remotes, so it does not.

The defaults for `git remote update` are particularly complicated; see [its documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote) for details.  This seems to be designed for larger mirror sites like one I used to run for a medium-size corporate setup.

---

#### Long

Let me quote this part for emphasis, as it were:

> ```
>   remotes/origin/master
>   remotes/remote/master
>   remotes/remote/carousel
>   remotes/bridgent/animate
> [snip]
> ```

If we take out the `remotes/` part from each line, we get:

```
origin/master
remote/master
remote/carousel
bridgent/animate
bridgent/enlarged-hover
bridgent/master
[snip]
```

If we further remove the part from the first remaining `/` onward, and eliminate duplicates, we get this list:

```
origin
remote
bridgent
```

This is a list of *remotes*.

If you run `git remote`, you should see this *same list of names*.  (If you don't, we have a somewhat different problem to solve than the one I think you are running into.)

Now:

> Here is a list of some remote branches on my GitHub repo:

Technically, these are not on your *GitHub* repository.  These are on (or in) your *local* repository, on your laptop or desktop computer.  There is another, different, repository over on GitHub; that one is your *GitHub* repository.

#### Remotes and remote-tracking names

Remember that Git is a *distributed* version control system.  As such, there are usually two, or three, or ten or maybe even millions of *repositories*.  Each repository has its own branch names.  What all the clones of some repository share is not *branches* but rather *commits*.  The *commits* are what get shared.  The *branch names* just help each repository remember *its* commits.  Each commit has a unique hash ID, which is the same in *every* repository.  A repository either *does* have that commit, which then has that hash ID; or it doesn't have that commit, and doesn't have that hash ID.

When you have your Git call up the other Git over on GitHub, your Git asks them about *their* commits.  They will say, e.g., *I have my `master` as commit `a123456...`*  Your Git checks: *do I have `a123456...`?*  If you *do* have it, your Git says *OK, I already have that one* and you don't need to get it.  If you *don't* have it, your Git says *Ah, please give me `a123456...`* and their Git now offers the *parent* commit of that commit.  Your Git checks to see if you have *that* commit.  If not, your Git asks for the parent of `a123456...` and they offer that commit's parent—`a123456...`'s grandparent—and your Git checks that hash ID, and so on.

In the end, your Git gets, from their Git, *all* the commits that they have on their `master`, that your Git does not have at all.  So now you have all of your commits *plus* all of their commits.  Your `master` might well *be* this `a123456...` commit.  Or, your `master` might be some other commit.  Whatever the case is, your Git now creates a new name, or updates an existing one, to remember *their* `master`.

Your Git's memory of their Git's branch names are your *remote-tracking names* for this particular "other Git".  This other Git over on GitHub has a URL; the *remote* name `origin` stores this URL.  But what if you have more than one "other Git"?

Your Git can call up a *different* Git repository, perhaps under the name `bridgent`.  This remote name, `bridgent`, stores a URL.  That's how your Git will call up *this* other Git.  When your Git calls up this other Git, they will say things like: *I have a branch named `animate` and a branch named `enlarged-hover` and a branch named `master`.  My `animate` is commit `b789abc...`, my `enlarged-hover` is commit `fedcba9...`, my `master` is ...*

Your Git will obtain from the `bridgent` Git any commits that *it* has, that you don't.  Then your Git will create or update your `bridgent/*` names.  These hold the hash IDs your Git got from the Git whose URL your Git has stored under the name `bridgent`.

So, since you have `origin` *and* `remote` *and* `bridgent`, this means your Git has recorded three separate *remotes*.  Each remote stores a URL; at that URL, some Git answers when you call its number.  *That* Git has a list of branch names.  Each branch name identifies some particular commit, by hash ID.  *Your* Git makes sure it has those commits too, and then creates or updates *remote-tracking names* for each of these other Git repositories.

The remote-tracking names for the Git your Git calls `origin` are listed under `origin/*`.  The remote-tracking names for the Git your Git calls `remote` are listed under `remote/*`.  The remote-tracking names for the Git your Git calls `bridgent` are listed under `bridgent/*`.  That's how your Git keeps all this stuff straight.

#### But `git branch -a` prints `remotes/origin/master` etc

If you use:

```
git branch
```

your Git lists your branch names.  These come out as `master`, `develop`, and so on.

If you use:

```
git branch -r
```

your Git lists your remote-tracking names.  These come out as `origin/master`, `bridgent/animate`, and so on.

*Both* sets of names are *shortened*.  The actual full name of your `master` is `refs/heads/master`.  The actual full name of `origin/master` is `refs/remotes/origin/master`.  The *branch* names have `refs/heads/` stripped off, and the *remote-tracking names* have `refs/remotes/` stripped off.

Putting those prefixes back on *guarantees* that the names can't collide.  If, for some strange reason, you create your own local branch named `origin/master`, its actual full name will be `refs/heads/origin/master`.  Your remote-tracking `origin/master` is really `refs/remotes/origin/master`.  Obviously, these two names are different, because of the different *prefix* parts.  Since Git uses the full names internally, *Git* won't get confused ... but since Git, and you, *see* the *shortened* names, *you* might get confused.  Don't create a local branch named `origin/master`!<sup>2</sup>

For whatever reason, though, `git branch -a` only strips the `refs/` part when listing remote-tracking names.  So `git branch -a` showed you `remotes/origin/master` for `origin/master`, `remotes/remote/carousel` for `remote/carousel`, and so on.

You *can*, if you like, delete remote-tracking names using the `git branch` command: give it `-d -r`, i.e., the delete *and* remote options.

You *can't*—at least, not successfully—have your Git ask the Git at *origin* to delete `remote/bridgent-carousel`:

> ```
> $ git push origin --delete remote/bridgent-carousel 
> error: unable to delete 'remote/bridgent-carousel': remote ref does not exist
> error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:Nostrad/<project_name>.git'
> ```

because the Git over at `origin` doesn't *have* this name.  It's the Git over at `bridgent` that has—or at least had at one time—the name `carousel`.  You can ask *them* to delete it, if you have permission.  Or, you can delete the *remote* in your Git repository.  The remote name, `bridgent-carousel`, stores the URL and enables your Git to have remote-tracking names of the form `bridgent/*`, or more fully, `refs/remotes/bridgent/*`.

---

<sup>2</sup>If you do, you can write `refs/heads/origin/master` and `refs/remotes/origin/master`, or just `heads/origin/master` and `remotes/origin/master`, to keep them straight.  Do this just long enough to rename or delete the local branch named `origin/master`.

Comment: I am thrilled to have a high ranking community SO contributor like @torek put so much care, time and effort answering my novice question. I now have a detailed resource which explains the nuances of managing local and remote git repositories all in the context of my project. I will refer back to this often. Thank you, torek. =)

Answer (score 0):

Here is:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:Nostrad/<project_name>.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:Nostrad/<project_name>.git (push)
remote  git@github.com:Nostrad/<former_project_name>.git (fetch)
remote  git@github.com:Nostrad/<former_project_name>.git (push)
bridgent git@github.com:bridgent/<project_name>.git (fetch)
```

I figured since there is a remote named "remote", it was pointing to a URL which no longer exists.

So I ran:

```
$ git remote remove remote
```

Then:

```
$ git remote remove bridgent
$ git fetch --prune
$ git push origin --delete
```

Some of the above may have been unnecessary or redundant but I invoked them anyways for good measure, being the novice that I am.

Here is my tree with all the obsolete branches removed:

```
git branch -a
warning: ignoring broken ref refs/remotes/remote/HEAD
* master
  origin
  restoration-effort2
  remotes/origin/master
```

I have reached my end result. I accomplished my original goal prior to viewing **@torek**’s extremely detailed and helpful explanation.  So I didn’t have the opportunity to try his **TL;DR** suggestions:

```
$ git fetch remote --prune
$ git fetch bridgent --prune
$ git fetch --all --prune
```