# fatal: A branch named 'gh-pages' already exists

Tags: git, github, gatsby

I made a template sale website (gatsby / react).  I cloned my template GitHub repo and changed the remote origin to a new private repo, pushing to which works fine.

I deploy to gh-pages with npm srcipt `"deploy": "gatsby build --prefix-paths && gh-pages -d public"`
The first time I ran this command it seemed to stall so I `control c`'d out of it. Now, when I try to deploy I get the error "fatal: A branch named 'gh-pages' already exists."

`git branch -a` shows:
`remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master`
`remotes/origin/gh-pages`
`remotes/origin/master`

But there is not a gh-pages branch on gitHub.

I tried `rm -rf node_modules/gh-pages/.cache` didn't work.
Also, `git push origin --delete gh-pages` which gave
"error: unable to delete 'gh-pages': remote ref does not exist".

I uninstalled and reinstalled gh-pages.

Comment: Is there more code I should show?

Comment: So you kept the .git directory from the initial clone? Have you looked into creating a github template? https://docs.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/creating-a-template-repository then creating your new repo from the template? https://docs.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/creating-a-repository-from-a-template

Comment: you may want to take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35941566/git-says-remote-ref-does-not-exist-when-i-delete-remote-branch

Comment: @ksav Thanks for the tip.  I think I will make the original repo a template.

Comment: It is a timeout because Github is waiting to enter your credentials to authenticate you. Mostly it's a screen on your desktop that we don't see most of the time

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant here, but in my case this appeared to be caused by switching to the local `gh-pages` branch when trying to run the `gh-pages` command. I switched back to `master` to fix the problem.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

I had to manually remove the folder `node_modules/.cache/gh-pages` to get the deployment to work.

Prior to this I had tried `git fetch --prune`, which removed `remotes/origin/gh-page`.  I don't know if pruning the branches was a necessary step or not.

Comment: I just `rm -rf node_modules/.cache/gh-pages` without `git fetch --prune` and it fixed the problem.

Comment: Thanks this worked! I just manually delete the `gh-pages` folder from `node_modules/.cache` from my editor (VSCode)

Comment: You can also add that  rm command to your predeploy script to save having to manually run it every time. 

"predeploy": "rm -rf node_modules/.cache/gh-pages && npm run build",

Comment: Yes this fixed the problem for me. I removed the remote branch gh-pages too, no prune needed.

Answer (score 23):

Just manually deleting the folder `node_modules/.cache/gh-pages` worked.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful.

Answer (score 19):

On windows, you can run `rm -rf node_modules/.cache/gh-pages`. or manually go to the `node_modules folder` and delete the `.cache/gh-pages`.

Answer (score 1):

delete **gh-pages** from **node_modules/.cache** then run :- **npm run deploy**
after this your page is Successfully publish on gh page

Answer (score 0):

if its instaled gllobaly it will be in this path:
windows path will be : `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gh-pages\.cache\<GITREPO>`

just remove this Dir

Answer (score -3):

create new repository in git hub and follow the steps as usual then the game is over!