# Git Auto-complete not working in bash

Tags: git, bash, autocomplete

I recently installed git. I am using Ubuntu 14.04. However the autocomplete feature is not working.

Whenever I type `git i` then <kbd>TAB</kbd> it should be `git init` but it doesn't happen so. I have tried everything mentioned in this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12399002/how-to-configure-git-bash-command-line-completion), still no success.

Whenever I do `git in` then <kbd>TAB</kbd> it seems like git is pinging unknown host. Below is the screenshot:

[image]

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 35):

Use this script for Ubuntu:

https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash

Read the documentation on how to set it up:

```
 To use these routines:

    1) Copy this file to somewhere (e.g. ~/.git-completion.bash).
    2) Add the following line to your .bashrc/.zshrc:
       source ~/.git-completion.bash
    3) Consider changing your PS1 to also show the current branch,
       see git-prompt.sh for details.
```

---

***A shorter solution:***

```
# install bash-completion via apt-get 
sudo apt-get install git bash-completion
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Install git & bash-completion

   ```
   sudo apt-get install git bash-completion -y
   ```
2. Download the **matched version** of git-completion.bash (You can change the version in the following download link)

> Example:
>
> - git v2.7.4:
>   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/v2.7.4/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash
> - git v2.17.1: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/v2.17.1/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash

3. Source this git-completion.bash

   ```
   . git-completion.bash
   ```

Enjoy it