# How can I remove autocomplete text after colon on fetch?

Tags: git

How to remove the `fetch` autocomplete feature, but only after the colon (:), on git?

I mean, after I type

`$ git fetch origin m<tab>`

, it autocompletes to

`$ git fetch origin master:master`

, and I want to autocomplete to just

`$ git fetch origin master`

, without the 'colon part' (like the previous versions of git).

Most times I'm already on master - or whatever branch, and I don't want to merge the remote branch into my local branch like this.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "on git"? The autocompletion will be done by whichever shell you're using. Which shell are you using?

Comment: I'm using the vanilla Linux shell (no customs). I mean, is there a way to do that? I'm not familiar with this kind of customization in the Linux shell...

Comment: You need to modify your `git-completion` script. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12399002/how-to-configure-git-bash-command-line-completion) out to know where to find it.

Comment: There is no vanilla Linux shell as such. A shell is just another program. Most likely, you mean bash.

Comment: Sure, I know, was just trying to say 'without any customization', but thanks for pointing out! :)

Comment: @MadPhysicist I guess I did

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks [**clmno**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5698740/clmno) for pointing this out.

I edited the file `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/git`, in the `__git_complete_remote_or_refspec ()` function, commenting the following lines:

```bash
case "$cmd" in
  fetch)
    #if [ $lhs = 1 ]; then
    #  __gitcomp_nl "$(__git_refs2 "$remote")" "$pfx" "$cur_"
    #else
      __gitcomp_nl "$(__git_refs)" "$pfx" "$cur_" # leave this uncommented
    #fi
    ;;
```

And it works as I <strike>want</strike> expect.