# shurtcut git branch checkout

Tags: git

I have a repository with a number of branches
`b1-long-name`, `b2-long-name`, `b3-too-long-name`

I want to be able to switch between branches fast. Also I want to run additional git command before I switch the branch.

I trying to approach that with a bash script, here is my custom script `gitSwitch.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

git reset #<-- additional command
git checkout -f b2-long-name
```

But the problem here I have to create a script per branch that I do not really want, I wonder how would you pass a param to the script so it will use a proper branch name?

`gitSwitch b1` -> would checkout `b1-long-name`
`gitSwitch b2` -> would checkout `b2-long-name`
and so on

Any ideas how to approach it best?

Comment: Just change checkout command to: `git checkout -f "$1-long-name"`

Comment: Have you considered just using shorter names for your branches?  What you call things in your repo is what you call them in your repo, any local branch can track any upstream branch.

Comment: @anubhava yeah but then I had to type full branch name in such case

Comment: @jthill unfortunately in that particular case they should go long

Answer (score 3):

> Any ideas how to approach it best?

For starters, install a [git completion script](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash) so that you can type something like `git checkout b1<tab>` instead of the complete long name. You can also make some shorter aliases for often used commands.

Comment: Completion scripts are probably the way to go here. I've never been satisfied with any of them myself though, as they make assumptions I disagree with. Fortunately the new `git restore` is likely to help here as a completer for `git restore` won't assume "branch" when I mean "file name" :-)

Comment: Thanks for an answer, I also want to script the additional command that actually much longer than `git reset` to execute before each `git checkout`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`git branch --list pattern`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt--l) and [store it in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54561526/6309)

In your case:

```
readarray -d '' branches < <(git branch --list "*$1*")
len=${#branches[@]}
```

If that array has only one element, then whatever you passed to your script is specific enough to isolate only one branch and you can switch to it.

If you have only one branch starting with `b1`, you can use `b1` as a parameter.

Obviously, using `git checkout -f "$1-long-name"` would not work since the suffix "`long-name`" varies between different branches.

Comment: OK, i see, how then you call that script?

Comment: @sreginogemoh `gitSwitch b1` for instance: you pass as a parameter any part of a branch name, specific enough to select only *one* branch (if you find more than one branch, your script should fail in error)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a **git alias** which would execute additionals commands.

```sh
# .git/config
[alias]
    sw = !git reset && git checkout $1 && :
```

To avoid typing long names, you could use **tab completion**.

```
git sw b1<tab>
```

If tab completion is not working, you might need configure it first. See the following:

[How to configure git bash command line completion?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12399002/2020827)

Comment: Is `&& :` for suppressing errors? First, why suppressing errors? Second, it should be `|| :`

Comment: @phd It does not work without `&& :`. Without it, the argument (branch name) is interpreted as a pathspec.

Comment: @phd: Errors are not suppresed. For example, if you give it a non existing branch name you will seen an error message.

Comment: seems like in that case I had to writhe full branch name

Comment: @sreginogemoh Try to type `b1` and then tp press `<tab><tab>`

Comment: @sergej does not complete really when hitting tab twice...do I need that https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash in order to get autocomplete working?

Comment: @sreginogemoh Probably, which OS are you using?