# "TAB" doesn't work in the terminal by using git

Tags: git, macos, terminal, tab-completion

I know that it is possible to make the commands complete by pressing the tab key. But for some reason this function does not work for me. Tell me please, how to fix it? My operating system is mac os.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12399002/how-to-configure-git-bash-command-line-completion Also this question would belong to superuser as it has nothing to do with coding but how to use a tool.

Comment: @DanielW. AFAIK questions about tools used for programming are allowed here.