# how to display the current directory and branch in git bash

Tags: bash, git, terminal

[My git bash terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZQem.png)
how do i make my git bash terminal look like the below one. i want to display the current working directory and the current branch. my terminal use to look like the below one. but for some reason it is only showing "->".
[My friends git bash terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVJIw.png)
please help me. i searched a lot for this question. i didn't find any answers.

Comment: That's the `git-prompt`, part of the completion scripts. You'll want to install it to your environment. https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/contrib/completion. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12399002/390278

Comment: It also comes included with git for windows. You might want to try reinstalling the latest version again.

Comment: How are you launching it?

Comment: @RamanSailopal i am launching it normally. i click on git bash which is on my taskbar.

Comment: @RamanSailopal please help me figure this out

Answer (score 3):

I'm on Windows and wanted to use git within MSYS2, not as a separate git bash terminal (which is what your friends seems to have). I downloaded Git for Windows and copied the following code from C:\Program Files\Git\etc\profile.d\git-prompt.sh into my bashrc file:

```
    if test -f ~/.config/git/git-prompt.sh
then
    . ~/.config/git/git-prompt.sh
else
    PS1='\[\033]0;$TITLEPREFIX:$PWD\007\]' # set window title
    PS1="$PS1"'\n'                 # new line
    PS1="$PS1"'\[\033[32m\]'       # change to green
    PS1="$PS1"'\u@\h '             # user@host<space>
    PS1="$PS1"'\[\033[35m\]'       # change to purple
    PS1="$PS1"'$MSYSTEM '          # show MSYSTEM
    PS1="$PS1"'\[\033[33m\]'       # change to brownish yellow
    PS1="$PS1"'\w'                 # current working directory
    if test -z "$WINELOADERNOEXEC"
    then
        GIT_EXEC_PATH="$(git --exec-path 2>/dev/null)"
        COMPLETION_PATH="${GIT_EXEC_PATH%/libexec/git-core}"
        COMPLETION_PATH="${COMPLETION_PATH%/lib/git-core}"
        COMPLETION_PATH="$COMPLETION_PATH/share/git/completion"
        if test -f "$COMPLETION_PATH/git-prompt.sh"
        then
            . "$COMPLETION_PATH/git-completion.bash"
            . "$COMPLETION_PATH/git-prompt.sh"
            PS1="$PS1"'\[\033[36m\]'  # change color to cyan
            PS1="$PS1"'`__git_ps1`'   # bash function
        fi
    fi
    PS1="$PS1"'\[\033[0m\]'        # change color
    PS1="$PS1"'\n'                 # new line
    PS1="$PS1"'$ '                 # prompt: always $
fi

MSYS2_PS1="$PS1"               # for detection by MSYS2 SDK's bash.basrc

# Evaluate all user-specific Bash completion scripts (if any)
if test -z "$WINELOADERNOEXEC"
then
    for c in "$HOME"/bash_completion.d/*.bash
    do
        # Handle absence of any scripts (or the folder) gracefully
        test ! -f "$c" ||
        . "$c"
    done
fi
```

To do this, open an instance of MSYS2, open bashrc using any editor, for example with nano type `nano ~/.bashrc`, scroll to the bottom of the file, and paste the above code in. New MSYS2 instances should look like your friend's!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Paste in `~/.profile` or in `~/.bash_profile`:

```
git_branch() {
     git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}


#update your prompt string
export PS1="[\u@\h \W]\\$\\$(git_branch)"
```

then `source ~/.profile` or `source ~/.bash_profile`

Answer (score 0):

This is what my prompt looks like:

[image]

Instead of showing the full path, it just shows the current branch and directory. It's designed with the file `git-prompt.sh` which contains:

```
PS1='\[\033]0;$TITLEPREFIX:\W\007\]' # set window title
PS1="$PS1"'\n'                       # new line
PS1="$PS1"'\[\033[35m\]'             # change to purple
PS1="$PS1"'git'                      # git user
if test -z "$WINELOADERNOEXEC"
then
    GIT_EXEC_PATH="$(git --exec-path 2>/dev/null)"
    COMPLETION_PATH="${GIT_EXEC_PATH%/libexec/git-core}"
    COMPLETION_PATH="${COMPLETION_PATH%/lib/git-core}"
    COMPLETION_PATH="$COMPLETION_PATH/share/git/completion"
    if test -f "$COMPLETION_PATH/git-prompt.sh"
    then
        . "$COMPLETION_PATH/git-completion.bash"
        . "$COMPLETION_PATH/git-prompt.sh"
        PS1="$PS1"'\[\033[36m\]'   # change color to cyan
        PS1="$PS1"'`__git_ps1` '   # bash function
    fi
fi
PS1="$PS1"'\[\033[33m\]'       # change to brownish yellow
PS1="$PS1"'@\W'                # current working directory
PS1="$PS1"'\n'                 # new line
PS1="$PS1"'\[\033[32m\]'       # change to green
PS1="$PS1"'> '                 # prompt: default $
PS1="$PS1"'\[\033[0m\]'        # change color
```

To edit the `git-prompt.sh` file, first go to your user profile folder. Example:

```
C:\Users\myProfile
```

Then go to the folder `\.config\git` Example:

```
C:\Users\myProfile\.config\git
```

Then create or edit the `git-prompt.sh` file, and paste in the code block above. The full path of `git-prompt.sh` should be:

```
C:\Users\myProfile\.config\git\git-prompt.sh
```

For reference, the default `git-prompt.sh` file is below:

```
if test -f /etc/profile.d/git-sdk.sh
then
    TITLEPREFIX=SDK-${MSYSTEM#MINGW}
else
    TITLEPREFIX=$MSYSTEM
fi

if test -f ~/.config/git/git-prompt.sh
then
    . ~/.config/git/git-prompt.sh
else
    PS1='\[\033]0;$TITLEPREFIX:$PWD\007\]' # set window title
    PS1="$PS1"'\n'                 # new line
    PS1="$PS1"'\[\033[32m\]'       # change to green
    PS1="$PS1"'\u@\h '             # user@host<space>
    PS1="$PS1"'\[\033[35m\]'       # change to purple
    PS1="$PS1"'$MSYSTEM '          # show MSYSTEM
    PS1="$PS1"'\[\033[33m\]'       # change to brownish yellow
    PS1="$PS1"'\w'                 # current working directory
    if test -z "$WINELOADERNOEXEC"
    then
        GIT_EXEC_PATH="$(git --exec-path 2>/dev/null)"
        COMPLETION_PATH="${GIT_EXEC_PATH%/libexec/git-core}"
        COMPLETION_PATH="${COMPLETION_PATH%/lib/git-core}"
        COMPLETION_PATH="$COMPLETION_PATH/share/git/completion"
        if test -f "$COMPLETION_PATH/git-prompt.sh"
        then
            . "$COMPLETION_PATH/git-completion.bash"
            . "$COMPLETION_PATH/git-prompt.sh"
            PS1="$PS1"'\[\033[36m\]'  # change color to cyan
            PS1="$PS1"'`__git_ps1`'   # bash function
        fi
    fi
    PS1="$PS1"'\[\033[0m\]'        # change color
    PS1="$PS1"'\n'                 # new line
    PS1="$PS1"'$ '                 # prompt: always $
fi

MSYS2_PS1="$PS1"     # for detection by MSYS2 SDK's bash.basrc

# Evaluate all user-specific Bash completion scripts (if any)
if test -z "$WINELOADERNOEXEC"
then
    for c in "$HOME"/bash_completion.d/*.bash
    do
        # Handle absence of any scripts (or the folder) gracefully
        test ! -f "$c" ||
        . "$c"
    done
fi
```

The default `git-prompt.sh` file may be found in any of the following folders:

`C:\Users\myProfile\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\etc\profile.d\git-prompt.sh`

`C:\Program Files\Git\etc\profile.d\git-prompt.sh`

Those can be edited directly instead of making a copy in your user profile. Editing those may change the prompt for all user profiles in your computer.

Answer (score -1):

Git bash is like any other bash so just run `pwd` (present working directory)
and for branch use `git branch -a`

Comment: i want my git terminal to  look like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVJIw.png