# Perl backticks not capturing output

Tags: perl, debugging, backticks

I have the following program snippet

```
my $nfdump_command = "nfdump -M /data/nfsen/profiles-data/live/upstream1  -T  -R ${syear}/${smonth}/${sday}/nfcapd.${syear}${smonth}${sday}0000:${eyear}/${emonth}/${eday}/nfcapd.${eyear}${emonth}${eday}2355 -n 100 -s ip/bytes -N -o csv -q | awk 'BEGIN { FS = \",\" } ; { if (NR > 1) print \$5, \$10 }'";
syslog("info", $nfdump_command);

my %args;
Nfcomm::socket_send_ok ($socket, \%args);
my @nfdump_output = `$nfdump_command`;
my %domain_name_to_bytes;
my %domain_name_to_ip_addresses;

syslog("info", Dumper(\@nfdump_output));

foreach my $a_line (@nfdump_output) {
    syslog("info", "LINE: " . $a_line);
}
```

Bug: @nfdump_output is empty. 
[image]

The $nfdump_command is correct and it printing output when ran individually

[image]

Comment: If you do the command in your shell, and add `1>/tmp/file`, does `/tmp/file` contain the desired output? If not, likely your command is printing to STDERR rather than STDOUT. The easiest way to capture STDERR or STDOUT+STDERR is with the module `Cature::Tiny`.

Comment: Without being able to run your command it is hard to say. Few questions - can you print the variable $nfdump_command.  What is the output from nfdump if you remove awk.

Comment: @justintime, I have printed the $nfdump_command in the screenshot. Output without awk: http://pastie.org/private/zsdki76zq25mp2azwzhyg

Comment: @David-SkyMesh: No, `awk`'s `print` writes to standard output by default. (And besides, if the output were going to STDERR, then we'd see it in the console, exactly because it wouldn't be captured by the backticks.)

Comment: @David-SkyMesh, Yes, The file does contain the output. http://pastie.org/private/s0jbcrvndrryqwyvuz8q

Comment: I'm wondering if the shell that Perl is launching for the backticks differs in some important way from the shell that you're starting out in. If you run `echo $SHELL` and `perl -e 'print qx/echo \$SHELL/'`, do they both print the same thing?

Comment: Both say  nfsen-destination-plugin git:(master) ✗
 ➜ perl -e 'print qx/echo \$SHELL/'
/bin/zsh

 nfsen-destination-plugin git:(master) ✗
 ➜ echo $SHELL
/bin/zsh

Comment: Sorry, correction: according to [this Stack Overflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3327022/978917), `perl -e 'print qx/echo \$SHELL/'` will print the name of your login shell, regardless of what shell is actually used for backticks. Can you try `perl -e 'print qx/echo \$0/'` instead?

Comment: @ruakh, It's sh
nfsen-destination-plugin git:(master) ✗
➜ perl -e 'print qx/echo \$0/'
sh

Comment: @ruakh, Ran sh from zsh and then copy pasted the same command:
http://pastie.org/private/ghgnwzy52gb7k9cvjxo6g

I see valid output.

Comment: Well then, I'm out of ideas, sorry. :-/

Comment: Can you look at [$?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Error-Variables) to check the exit value of the backtick process?

Comment: I added  
{ my @nfdump_output = `$nfdump_command`;
syslog("info", "EXIT: $_"); }

And output was empty:
{ Jan  4 14:17:14 suren-VirtualBox nfsen[5098]: EXIT: }

Comment: $? has the exit value of the backtick process.  If it is not 0 then you can possibly decode it for some hint as to what went wrong.  I don't think $_ does you much good in this situation.

Comment: @dms, My bad, I got -1 when I printed $?

Comment: @ruakh Re: awk printing to stdout -- that assumes execution got that far.

Answer (score 0):

This program was working for sometime and then it broke. Couldn't figure out why. After moving my development setup to another virtual machine, I found out that using **absolute path to nfdump** fixes it