# Python activating environment variables

Tags: python, environment-variables, virtualenv

Using environment variables, successful in creating vartualenv but when I am trying to activate it by myenv/bin/activate it says badly places ()'s.

```
virtualenv my env
source myenv/bin/activate
badly placed()'s
```

I've also tried ./myenv/bin/activate. How do I solve this? where should I place ()'s?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

If you use *csh or fish, use `activate.csh` or `activate.fish` instead of `activate`:

```
falsetru@ubuntu:/tmp$ tcsh
ubuntu:/tmp> virtualenv aa
New python executable in aa/bin/python
Installing setuptools............done.
Installing pip...............done.
ubuntu:/tmp> source aa/bin/ac
activate          activate.csh      activate.fish     activate_this.py
ubuntu:/tmp> source aa/bin/activate      # <----------------
Badly placed ()'s.
ubuntu:/tmp> source aa/bin/activate.csh  # <----------------
[aa] ubuntu:/tmp>
```

Comment: consider editing: find which shell you using echo $shell if ../csh then activate.csh etc

Comment: @RubberDuck, `echo $SHELL` does not show current shell, but the login shell. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327013/how-to-determine-the-current-shell-im-working-on

Answer (score -2):

I had trouble because of typing

```
".virtualenv/MyEnv/bin/activate"
```

instead of

```
". virtualenv/MyEnv/bin/activate"
```

missed the blank space.
try!