# How to check if currently running shell is BusyBox

Tags: linux, shell, busybox

I tried different variants

```
echo $0
echo $shell
echo $SHELL
ps -p $$
```

but none of them can give a distinctive output. I can do something like this but it's ugly and hackish:

```
if ls --help 2>&1 | grep BusyBox; then
    echo "it is BusyBox"
else
    echo "it is NOT BusyBox"
fi
```

Comment: I find that there's no accurate way to do that. Your best luck is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327013/how-to-determine-the-current-shell-im-working-on. And @Vality's answer. Question: Is it only meant to run in Linux systems?

Comment: I have to give up then, at least now I know there is no better way. Ye, I need it for Linux only, appropriate tag added.

Comment: If it's only for Linux I can give another suggestion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another way requiring Linux and `readlink`:

```
#!/bin/ash
exe=`exec 2>/dev/null; readlink "/proc/$$/exe"`
case "$exe" in
*/busybox)
    echo "It's a busybox shell."
    ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 2):

Personally I favour:

```
if ps ax -o pid,comm | grep `echo $$` | grep busybox ; then
    echo "it is BusyBox"
fi
```

Which is a fair check to ensure you are running busybox shell.

This works by having ps generate a list of pids vs program names then finding our pid and checking if the program name contains busybox.

Comment: BusyBox version of ps doesn't seem to support arguments.

Comment: @svlasov Strange, my busybox seemed to work file with that, it supports only `-o` and `-T`. (I have tested the command on my own system running BusyBox v1.22.1.) Perhaps you need to update? Is your BusyBox very old?

Comment: I have v1.20.2 but I'm not sure if it's possible to install a newer version.

Comment: @svlasov You could probably use /bin/ps instead of ps to force it to not use the built-in. You could then do an error check so if ps does not exist it will assume busybox. However what distro are you using? Many provide up to date busyboxes.

Comment: It is a Sitara board from TI. My /bin/ps is a symlink to /bin/busybox. By chance I can be running full bash or zsh, so relying on file check is not accurate.

Comment: http://tinderbox.dev.gentoo.org/default-linux/arm/armv7a-hardfloat-linux-gnueabi/unstable/sys-apps/busybox-1.22.1.tbz2 Have a new busybox. (should run on your board.) If you like this should let you use the newer commands.

Answer (score 2):

Might not be perfect but this is how I check:

```
test -h /bin/ls # busybox or other single binary system
test -h /bin/ls && [[ $(readlink /bin/ls) =~ busybox ]] # it is busybox
```

Comment: Above code not work on alpine, i have to change to:


test -h /bin/ls && [[ \`readlink /bin/ls\` =~ busybox ]]

Anyway, it give me good idea for how to solve this issue, plus +1

Update the above answer, please approve.