# get linux shell name

Tags: linux, bash, shell

In my program I need to output to user which shell he is using. So in file `/etc/udate-motd.d/00-header` I wrote `printf "$SHELL"` but the problem is that even when I switching my shell to zsh, $SHELL is still equal to /bin/bash. I searched through the internet and found that I can bo it by using `MyShell='ps -hp $$'`, and here is again a problem. When I use it `MyShell` is a string with number of processes (`/etc/update-motd.d/00-header` is also there) but there no word `zsh`.

So how can I understand which shell use the logging in person.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327013/how-to-determine-the-current-shell-im-working-on) is at least closely related, if not a duplicate.

Comment: @ajp15243 , thanks a lot! did find it, sorry for duplicate :(

Answer (score 2):

"the internet" gave you one kind of ps syntax.  You've tagged this linux, so don't use BSD syntax. Try this:

```
ps hp $$ -o cmd
```

no dash

Comment: In this way I keep getting: `/bin/bash /etc/update-motd.d/00-header`

Answer (score 0):

The users shell is determined in /etc/passwd. Why not take the information from there? You could

```
grep $USER /etc/passwd | cut -f7 -d:
```

to get the shell.

Comment: This gives the shell declared to be the login shell of the user, not the shell that the user is actually running (e.g. you could start `xterm -e /bin/zsh` or `exec /bin/zsh`)

Comment: agreed. But neither of your examples involves logging in. And op uses the phrase "So how can I understand which shell use the logging in person." which is written in "present progressive" indicating that determening the shell happends while $USER is in the process of logging in. I may be wrong though since i am no english native speaker...

Comment: Yes, I really need to know which shell is using a person, which is trying to login in `ctrl+alt+f4`, but as all others you solution doesnt work. Ur solution is just hangs and nothing more. I need to use `ctrl+c`. All others is bad because when I change my shell by `chsh -s /bin/zsh` $SHELL is still `/bin/bash`