# 'unexpected redirection' within bash script in chroot environment

Tags: linux, bash

In a batch script I have things like:

```
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password PASSWORDHERE'
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password PASSWORDHERE'
```

Which throws the error message `unexpected redirection` associated with such lines, why is this happening and how can I get around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably running under a different [shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327013/how-to-determine-the-current-shell-im-working-on) (e.g.: plain `sh`)

Execute the script with `bash`.

Comment: I do use `bash`, the exact same code, and I get the same issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327013/how-to-determine-the-current-shell-im-working-on