# Fish shell how to get the PID of the process started in the background

Tags: fish

While in FiSH (Friendly Interactive SHell) I can start a process in the background (`something &`). However, if I try to retrieve the process id of the process (`PID=$!`) I get an error from fish:

```
fish: Unknown command “PID=$!”. Did you mean “set PID $!”? For information on assigning values to variables, see the
help section on the set command by typing “help set”.
PID=$!: command not found
```

How can I retrieve the PID of the background process?

Comment: I cannot start an aliased command (`alias zath='zathura'`) in the background (`zath book.pdf &`) in `fish` *unlike* `bash`. It might be a feature lack or bug :(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using [process expansion](https://fishshell.com/docs/2.7/index.html#expand-process), you could write

```
set PID %1          # if you know it's the first background job
set PID %something  # if you know it's the only "something" running
```

Note that this feature is [**removed** in fish version 3](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/blob/master/CHANGELOG.rst#fish-30b1-released-december-11-2018).

Otherwise, we can use the [`jobs`](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#jobs) command

```
set PID (jobs -l | awk '{print $2}')    # just get the pid
jobs -l | read jobid pid cpu state cmd  # get all the things
```

Comment: I also use `set PID (jobs -lp)` instead of using `awk`. The "-p" argument gives the PID

Answer (score 6):

From [fish version 3](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/relnotes.html#syntax-changes-and-new-commands-2), you can use `$last_pid` as a replacement for `%last` to get the PID of the last background job.

Comment: Be careful with this one.  Currently this doesn't work as expected when used in a function.  In a function, `$last_pid` will refer to the parent shell itself, unless `status job-control full` is set (not currently default).  See [this Github issue](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/7692).