# How can a script know which shell is executing it

Tags: shell, sh

I'd like to know if a given script is running under Ash, Dash, Bash, ZSH or something else.

The script may or may not have a shebang line, and it can be executed either directly (`my-script.sh`) or as an argument to a shell interpreter (`sh my-script.sh`).

What's the most straightforward way to find that out?

Edit: After reading the answers below and the duplicate question, I've found this to be the most simple and reliable way to find the name of the shell executing a script under Linux:

```
show_shell() { basename "$(readlink -f /proc/$$/exe)" ;}
```

Comment: How is this script being invoked? Does the script have a "#!' line?

Comment: Edited to clarify that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine the current shell I'm working on?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327013/how-to-determine-the-current-shell-im-working-on)

Answer (score 1):

There is no universal, standard way of getting the name that the current shell identifies as.

Prouder shells leave markers you can check:

```
[ "$BASH_VERSION" ] && echo bash
[ "$ZSH_VERSION" ] && echo zsh
[ "$KSH_VERSION" ] && echo ksh
```

More humble shells like `ash` and `dash`, do not.

This may not be a problem if this point is to run shell specific code, since `ash` and `dash` don't include a lot of features outside POSIX anyways.

---

If (and only if) you are on Linux, you might be able to glean some insights from `/proc/$$/exe`:

```
$ dash -c 'ls -l /proc/$$/exe'
lrwxrwxrwx 1 me me 0 Jun 13 11:46 /proc/10933/exe -> /bin/dash
```

However, for `sh` it will just say `/bin/sh`, regardless of which shell actually implements it, though `/bin/sh` may or may not be a symlink or hardlink to a more identifiable binary.

Comment: Your example regarding the use of `$$` works for Dash, but for Bash and ZSH, the path to the inner command (`ls`) is printed:

`bash -c 'ls -l /proc/$$/exe'`
`/proc/3576/exe -> /bin/ls`

Comment: @Elifarley Good point. This is due to bash/zsh being clever when there's only a single command to be executed. If you use this as part of a script (or add a dummy `; true`), it will show up correctly.

Comment: So I'd declare a function like this:
`show_shell() { readlink -f /proc/$$/exe ;}`

Comment: Aside: an important other one to check for is fish, which is "proud" in this taxonomy.

```shell
[ "$FISH_VERSION" ] && echo fish`
```