# How to write shell script to find out shell type using Shell Script

Tags: linux, shell

In Linux, how to find out shell type using Shell script. 
echo $0- will print shell type through cmd line 
$SHELL - print Default Shell type.

Comment: Isn't `echo $SHELL` what you want?

Comment: $SHELL - will display Default shell.. Im looking when i change shell from bash to ksh or bash to csh.. How do we find shell type using shell script

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine the current shell I'm working on?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327013/how-to-determine-the-current-shell-im-working-on)

Comment: im looking through Shell Script.. not through cmd line

Comment: @Name Cool. Choose whichever fits your needs.

Comment: thank u for solution.. But   how we can get using Shell Script  ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
ps -p `ps -o ppid= -p $$` -o comm=
```

it is a little bit dirty, but it works fine for me.

Explanation: `ps -o ppid= -p $$` gives you the parent process id of the current running process (your script e.g.)

`ps -p`...`-o comm=` tells you the name of the process passed with -p.

Comment: thank u for solution.. But   how we can get using Shell Script  ?