# Bash scripting shebang

Tags: bash, shell, shebang

I have this simple script:

```
#!/bin/dash
echo "Shell used:" $SHELL
```

I expected to get:

```
Shell used: /bin/dash
```

But instead of the output is:

```
Shell used: /bin/bash
```

I'm running the script as:

```
./my_script.sh
```

Comment: dash doesn't modify or set `$SHELL` environment.

Comment: Thank you, all these terms are quite new to me

Comment: Strongly related to [How to determine the current shell I'm working on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327013/how-to-determine-the-current-shell-im-working-on)

Comment: about SHELL environment variable https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/277944/what-sets-the-shell-environment-variable

Comment: Your script just prints contents of `$SHELL` variable inherited from the parent process. For example, if you ran your script like that: `SHELL=aaa ./script.sh` it would print: `Shell used: aaa`.