# What is the purpose of $SHELL?

Tags: shell

In multiple different shells, the value of SHELL remains mostly constant:

```
bash$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
bash$ csh
csh$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
csh$ exec tcsh
csh$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
csh$ exec ksh
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
$ exec dash
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
$ exec zsh
zsh$ echo $SHELL
banana
zsh$ exec bash
bash$ echo $SHELL
banana
```

Since `$SHELL` is not useful for determining the currently running shell, what is its purpose?

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the question, SHELL is (almost) completely worthless for determining the currently running shell.  Although there is *some* correlation between the value of $SHELL and the user's login shell, that relationship is tenuous at best and $SHELL cannot be used to reliably determine which shell you are currently running.

Instead, the purpose of SHELL is to allow the user to communicate a preference to the system, similar to the use of PAGER or EDITOR.  If a process needs the user to edit a file, it should examine EDITOR and open an editor that the user likes.  If a process needs to present textual information to the user, it should check the value of PAGER to determine which program to use.  If a process needs to invoke a SHELL to execute commands, it should execute the shell specified in SHELL.  SHELL should probably not be used in quite the same way as PAGER or EDITOR, which really are just user preferences.  It is more likely to be used to work around certain behaviors.  For instance, if `/bin/sh` is a bloated shell, or some not-strictly-standards conforming shell that causes some obscure error, or even if `/bin/sh` actually fixes bugs that older scripts rely on for correct behavior, the user (or the system, via default startup files) may prefer to set SHELL to something like `/usr/xpg4/bin/sh` to side-step those issues.

Note that `ksh` documents a slightly different usage of SHELL, and states "The pathname of the shell is kept in the environment."  Inspecting the code (https://github.com/ksh2020/ksh/blob/master/src/lib/libast/path/pathshell.c#L104), we see that the documentation is not quite accurate, as reflected in the behavior seen above.  The `bash` documentation states "This variable expands to the full pathname to the shell.  If it is not set when the shell starts, bash assigns to it the full pathname of the current user's login shell"

It is very likely that most users will set SHELL to the value of their login shell, so `bash`'s behavior is reasonable.  After all, if you have a favorite shell, it makes sense to use it as your login shell and to set it in SHELL.  On the other hand, if you are using
tclsh or python as your login shell, it would make sense to set SHELL to `/bin/sh` or similar.   Since many users will set SHELL to their login shell there is a correlation between the value of SHELL and the shell you are currently using, but this relationship is certainly not guaranteed.

In the question, note the value of `$SHELL` in `zsh` is set to `banana`, and that value persists into the next invocation of `bash`.  This is a bit pathological, but might be instructive.  What is happening here is simply that the value of SHELL in the `$HOME/.zshrc` was set to the string `banana`.  When `bash` was invoked, that value was retained.  It is the prerogative of the user to set SHELL to any value they like, and it does not need to be in any way related to the current shell nor even to make any sense.