# [Shell]]Can't change from bash to ksh

Tags: docker, shell

#### What I would like to accomplish.

I have a centos container in Docker and am trying to change the shell to ksh using the following Dockerfile and command, but it appears to be sh.

**Expected behavior**.

```
echo ${SHELL}
/bin/ksh
```

**Current behavior**

```
echo ${SHELL}
/bin/sh
```

I don't know the cause of the problem, and I don't know how to solve it.
I would appreciate it if someone could tell me what is going on.

#### Dockerfile & Command

Dockerfile

```
FROM centos:centos7

RUN yum install ksh -y
RUN chsh -s /bin/ksh root

CMD ["/bin/ksh"].
```

build

```
docker build -t mybashimage .
[+] Building 33.5s (7/7) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile 0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 129B 0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore 0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B 0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/centos:centos7 0.0s
 => CACHED [1/3] FROM docker.io/library/centos:centos7 0.0s
 => [2/3] RUN yum install ksh -y 31.5s
 => [3/3] RUN chsh -s /bin/ksh root 0.4s
 => exporting to image 1.6s
 => => exporting layers 1.6s
 => => writing image sha256:ffefefa6641e2cb21bd90aec5b257c130ade5bb11d02cd7604d6a3c7baf2be10 0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/mybashimage
```

Launching containers.

```
docker run -it --rm mybashimage:latest
```

Check the shell.

```
echo ${SHELL}
/bin/sh
```

#### What I tried

user (root) shell has changed => root's shell was changed to /bin/ksh

```
head /etc/passwd
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/ksh
bin:x:1:1:bin:/bin:/sbin/nologin
```

Confirm login user.

```
whoami
root
```

Check shells

```
# cat /etc/shells
/bin/sh
/bin/bash
/usr/bin/sh
/usr/bin/bash
/bin/ksh
/bin/rksh
```

Check shell

```
# ps -p $$
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
    1 pts/0    00:00:00 ksh
```

#### Purpose of this question

The purpose was to create a ksh environment for the shell. Since my own Mac has zsh and I did not want to touch it, I used docker.
I believed that echo ${SHELL} would show me information about the shell I was currently using, so I used echo ${SHELL} to check the shell, but /bin/sh was displayed and I was worried that /bin/ksh was really being used. That is why I asked this question.

Comment: You should "check your shell" by calling `ps -p $$`

Comment: @MSpiller Thanks.I tried ps -p $$ and added that. Looking at the results of this, it appears that ksh is working. However, no matter how many times I tried, TIME did not change from 0 seconds.

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd need to do this.  A container is a temporary environment running a single process, and anything you do in an interactive shell will be lost as soon as the container exits, so you shouldn't be directly using the shell much; and if you do have a script that works only with ksh, normal mechanisms like script shebang lines will pick the correct interpreter.

Comment: @DavidMaze Use as an isolated developer environment is often pushed as a use-case for using Docker containers. It's not unreasonable to want a specific shell for that environment. (True, you generally wouldn't be developing as *root*, but whatever issue is at play here would seem to be relevant for any user, unless OP can confirm that it's *only* root whose default shell cannot be changed.)

Comment: SHELL is an environment variable, and its value is (perhaps counter-intuitively) almost completely unrelated to the shell that is currently running.  It's not clear to me what you are trying to do, but if you want the value of SHELL to be "/bin/ksh", you should just assign it.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74376285/what-is-the-purpose-of-shell

Comment: I'm not sure what the confusion is. OP used `chsh` to change the preferred shell for `root` to `ksh`, but the value of `SHELL` does not reflect that as (I think) it should.

Comment: In other words, your first expectation is wrong.  In `ksh`, you should not expect SHELL to equal `/bin/ksh` any more than you should expect PAGER to be `cat`.  `PAGER` is often set to `less` or `more` and sometime `cat` but very rarely is it `ls`.  Similarly, `SHELL` is often `/bin/sh`, but you can make it whatever you want.  Its value is unrelated to which shell is currently running.  `ksh` documentation makes claims about the value of SHELL, but the documentation conflicts with the code.

Comment: @here The purpose was to create a ksh environment for the shell. Since my own Mac has zsh and I did not want to touch it, I used docker.
I believed that echo ${SHELL} would show me information about the shell I was currently using, so I used echo ${SHELL} to check the shell, but /bin/sh was displayed and I was worried that /bin/ksh was really being used. That is why I asked this question.

Comment: Are changes to the root login shell not honored?

Comment: @chepner Thankyou.I just created a testuser and changed it to ksh and now I get /bin/ksh with echo ${SHELL}. maybe root can't change the shell.

Comment: For example, I changed the login shell on my machine to `zsh`; `SHELL` gets intialized to `/bin/zsh` when I log in. If I change `ksh` to `zsh` in the OP's Dockerfile, and get rid of the `CMD` directective, `bash` is still started as the login shell. (So my two questions would be, is the initial value of `SHELL` shell-specific, and are changes to `/etc/passwd` honored for root?)

Comment: This question might be better asked at unix.stackexchange.com, as there are several aspects to the question that aren't related to programming.

Comment: @chepner It would be very interesting to track down where SHELL is getting changed.  On your machine, is it being explicitly set in a shell specific dotfile in $HOME or in /etc (eg, /etc/zshrc, or whatever startup file zsh uses)?

Comment: @WilliamPursell Not that I can see. I see now that I have glossed over the distinction between login and preferred shell, but mainly because I've always noticed `SHELL` to seemingly be initialized to be my login shell.

Comment: (I'm not entirely sure where it might come from on macOS. `/etc/passwd` isn't used, for example; I don't even have an entry there, so I'm not sure where `chsh` records the fact that `/bin/zsh` is my login shell. OpenDirectory promises to be a rabbit hole I'm not terribly interested in diving into :) )

Answer (score 0):

`${SHELL}` is not a reliable source to check your current running shell. use `${$}` instead.
and your comment about `TIME`, that's normal since it is not using any cpu time.

if You want to change the time run a command that uses cpu and check it from another terminal like:
shell 1:

```
echo ${$}

# copy shell pid

while : ; do echo hi ; done
```

shell 2:

```
ps -Fp ${shell_pid}
```

Comment: OP is not trying to check the currently running shell; they are trying to confirm that the `chsh` command actually *did* change the preferred shell to `ksh`.

Comment: @chepner what is the difference? when you change default shell of a user with `chsh` and spawn a shell, then it is your running shell. with `${$}` you can check what is your running shell(default shell).

Comment: OP is specifically pointing out that `SHELL`, which is supposed to contain the name of the user's preferred shell, does *not*.

Comment: @chepner The "user's preferred shell" is unrelated to either the currently running shell, the login shell, or the gecos field.  Typically, the system startup files will set SHELL to a value like `/bin/sh`; if the user doesn't explicitly change it in their startup files, it will retain that value despite invocations of `chsh` or  modifications to /etc/passwd.

Comment: On my machine (macOS), `SHELL` is set to `/bin/zsh` (my login shell) with no mention of `SHELL` in any applicable configuration file that I am aware of. That's why I'm now wondering if the initial value of `SHELL` (if not inherited) may be shell-specific.

Comment: I believe `bash` will set SHELL to a reasonable value if SHELL is not set when bash is invoked, and I suspect many shells behave the same.  I don't know if that behavior is specified in any standard, but it wouldn't surprise me if that's all that's  happening.  Bottom line; don't rely on SHELL; it doesn't really tell you much.

Answer (score 0):

I just created a testuser and changed it to ksh and now I get /bin/ksh with echo ${SHELL}.