Executing shell script with `sh foo.sh` throws a `foo.sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected`
Story
When I run sh foo.sh I get foo.sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
ARR=("apple" "banana" "cherry")

for i in ${ARR[@]};
do
    echo $i
done


but when I run /bin/bash or /usr/bin/zsh` I get expected result;
/usr/bin/zsh foo.sh
ARR
apple
banana
cherry

My Checks
Echo
echo $SHELL 
/usr/bin/zsh  

/etc/shells
my /etc/shells is the following
# /etc/shells: valid login shells
/bin/sh
/usr/bin/zsh
/usr/bin/sh
/bin/bash
/usr/bin/bash
/bin/rbash
/usr/bin/rbash
/usr/bin/dash
/bin/zsh
/usr/bin/tmux

I'm stumped on what is going on here. As far as my understanding sh <script> should be using the defined shell for the machine.
Thank you in advance.

In some distros sh is a modified version of bash to resemble the old sh. Check ls -l /usr/bin/sh lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Aug 22 05:05 /usr/bin/sh -> bash. It's a symlink in my case.

Which shell does sh point to? A POSIX shell doesn't have arrays, so ARR=("apple" "banana" "cherry") is a syntax error.

/bin/sh is most likely dash on your system

I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate. You have to either add a shebang #!/usr/bin/env bash or call bash foo.sh.

Also see Difference between sh and Bash.

If you add a #! /bin/sh shebang line to the code then Shellcheck identifies several problems with it, including the cause of the error.  The report that it produces includes links to more information about the problems and how to fix them.  It's a good idea to run Shellcheck on all new and modified shell code.

Note that the expansion of $SHELL is completely irrelevant.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74376286/140750
